# Gstreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_poll_read_control: assertion 'set != NULL' failed - (Error comes after multiple execution of test cases)

Tags: python, automated-tests, gstreamer, video-capture

We are using Gstreamer to capture the video. We have built a test runner that executes multiple test cases for multiple numbers of iterations. After executing for over a certain number of times, the terminal shows up the following error traceback from Gstreamer:

```
(python:4375): Gstreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:11:07.491: gst_poll_read_control: assertion 'set != NULL' failed
```

This error continuously comes up after then, which hampers the execution of our test cases.

Comment: The situation sounds to me like a file descriptor leak. If you're using watchers, make sure that you remember to remove the watcher when bringing the pipeline down.

Comment: Have you solved the error? and what's your gstreamer version?